# How to convert an enum to a byte array in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I have an enum and I want to pass one of its value to an Objective-C method expecting `char *` directly instead of creating another variable. What should I do?

e.g.

```
typedef enum { value1 = 0xAA, value2 = 0xBB, value3 = 0xCC } myValue;

NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

// want to pass in the enum directly as char * but won't work

[data appendBytes:(char *){ value1 } length: 1];

// this will work, why? and is this the best way?

[data appendBytes:(char []){ value1 } length: 1];
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the method to receive? It wants a `char*`. What do you expect the enum value to end up as when passed as a `char*`?

Comment: The byte value that it represents.  Let me edit my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of using `(char[]){value1}` to get a `char*` that points to `value1` interpreted as a `char` is perfectly legitimate. Equivalent code might look like

```
char achar = value1;
[data appendBytes:&achar length:1];
```

But your `(char[]){value1}` is obviously one fewer lines of code, so I say go with that.

---

For any who are confused, `(char[]){value1}` is a [compound literal](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html). It's a way of constructing any sort of value, including aggregates, as an expression. In this particular case, it's constructing an array of `char`s, with the initializer containing one element, so this constructs a `char[1]`, which then gets implicitly converted to a pointer when passed to the method. Interestingly, you can even take the address of compound literals (although the address is only going to be valid for the full expression in which the compound literal is found), so an equivalent in this case would be `&(char){value1}`.

Comment: Why do you need the char * cast?

Comment: @ValentinRadu: Err, you don't. Sorry, wasn't thinking. I'll fix that.

Comment: @ValentinRadu `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by the standard.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you're right, but in C it helps knowing what the parameter is without having a look at the function definition. Of course, that's useless for objective-c, it's pretty obvious what 1 is from the method definition, but I'm used to do it anyway.